# Cannot import module in python shell or py files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I use xubuntu 14.04.3,and its default python version is python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.3.Then I download python 2.7.10 source code and compile install with command

```
./configure
make
sudo make -i install
```

`make` shows some modules not found:

```
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _ssl
_tkinter           bsddb185           bz2
dbm                gdbm               readline
sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

then I run `sudo pip install pyftpdlib` to install a module,then I can see it installs ok

```
pip show pyftpdlib
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pyftpdlib
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: Very fast asynchronous FTP server library
Home-page: https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib/
Author: Giampaolo Rodola'
Author-email: g.rodola@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

But when I import pyftpdlib in python shell or .py, python shows error`ImportError: No module named pyftpdlib`
If I modified PYTHONPATH ,import modules is ok ,I should modified root and normal user, and when using sudo ,it's still shows cannot find module.
How to solve this problem? or return to the default states.

Answer (score 0):

check which version [are you using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script). Then, run pip on the appropiate version using `python -m pip` (or `python27` or `python3` or whatever version you´re using on your script.

Also, you can specify which version should your script use by [shebanging at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170827/how-tell-python-script-to-use-particular-version)

Comment: I'm sure I'm using 2.7.10

Comment: @Ezio I mean, are you sure you installed in in 2.7.10? Check with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules